# Exception: Jupyter command `jupyter-C:/spark/datamaking4.py` not found

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, jupyter

I wish to connect kafka producer to pyspark structured streaming on windows.
I use the following command

`C:\spark> .//bin//spark-submit --packages org.apache.spark:spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.12:3.1.2 datamaking4.py`

but i keep on getting the error 'Exception: Jupyter command `jupyter-C:/spark/datamaking4.py` not found.'.

The directory 'C:/spark/datamaking4.py' is where my python file is and its available there

I have also verified that my scala and spark version is well specified. I have tried submitting it using power shell, pycharm and jupter notebook and i still get the same error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\amberex\anaconda3\Scripts\jupyter-script.py", line 10, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "C:\Users\amberex\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\jupyter_core\command.py", line 247, in main
    command = _jupyter_abspath(subcommand)
  File "C:\Users\amberex\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\jupyter_core\command.py", line 133, in _jupyter_abspath
    raise Exception(
Exception: Jupyter command `jupyter-C:/spark/sparkstream.py` not found.
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.apache.spark.util.ShutdownHookManager).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
```

Comment: Your Spark command is correct, and Spark doesn't require Jupyter, so if you're using cmd/powershell, then I don't understand why your error mentions jupyter. What extra configurations have you done related to jupyter or your Python environment and Spark?

Comment: I don't understand also, I tried to create virtual environment with only the necessary packages to run the kafka and pyspark and i still get that. For the system variable: PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON= jupyter, PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON_OPTS=notebook, SPARK_HOME=C:\spark, . For my user variable path :C:\spark\bin, C:\hadoop\hadoop-3.2.0\bin.